# Why is my for loop crashing on a vector of doubles?

Tags: c++

This for loop always crashes immediately:

```
for (auto i = v.size() - 1; i >=0; --i);
```

Obviously I have a whole load of code in the loop, and v is a vector of doubles. I'm trying to iterate over them in reverse order.

What is going on here?

Comment: Does the compiler not give you a [warning](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/861e29c98a27fbca)?

Comment: It's a vector, you want to iterate, in reverse. Why not use a reverse iterator then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable i will be an unsigned type.

That can never be less than zero.

Eventually you will access an element outside the vector as i will wrap around to the largest possible unsigned value rather than going negative

Answer (score 5):

```
for (auto i = v.size() - 1; i >=0; --i);
```

Look at vector::size() method - it returns usually **unsigned int** (on strange platforms it might be other unsigned type)! So your `i` variable will have unsigned type.

When your loop will come to step `i == 0` it will decrement it and `i` will have value `2^32 - 1 == UNSIGNED_INT_MAX` (or other positive value if you work on strange platform - see vector::size_type on your platform to see underlying type). So it will never be less then 0, it will never stop your loop. I guess when it turns so big it crashes becouse it goes out of range, but i don't see whole code to be sure.

See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) - look for `size_type` typedef - it says its unsigned type.

You might want to use reverse iterators (see @NathanOliver's response), though i'm not very fond of them in simple loops.

Comment: I've edited answer, last line. vector::size_type is typedef of: `an unsigned integral type that can represent any non-negative value of difference_type`. It makes sense since size can't be less then 0, right?

Comment: The answer makes it sound like `unsigned int` specifically, not a choice of type.

Comment: @chris - right, i've updated my answer to note that unsigned int will be usually on major platform, on others it can be other unsigned type.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking how would you handle reversely iterating through a vector?

Comment: @NathanOliver - There are many ways, your's (reverse iterators) is most 'clean' and has least chance of introducing bugs. So if i were to write good quality code to last long time - i'd use reverse iterators. If i were writing small app which had to work fast (and small source) - i'd cast ::size() to signed type or make some trick. Since C+11 and auto it's easy to use begin(), end() etc. but before it was so slappy, so not-elegant code writing all those `::iterator` or `::const_iterator`s... Now i'd recommend reverse iterator since it's best (unless performance is needed).

Answer (score 3):

Since `i` is unsigned it will never be less than 0.  It will wrap around to the maximum value that it can hold instead.

If you want to iterate through a vector backwards then you should use a [`reverse_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator)

```
std::vector<int> foo = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
for (auto it = foo.rbegin(); it != foo.rend(); ++it)
    std::cout << *it << " ";
```

This will output

```
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

Answer (score 1):

What Bathsheba said: the auto type is an unsigned.  So decrementing 0 becomes some large positive number, which is >= 0 so the loop continues, but that value is outside the vector's range and causes the crash.